# Настройка вида графика в Google Chart

Tags: html, svg, диаграммы

```
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

    function drawLineColors() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'X');
                    data.addColumn('number', '1');
                    data.addColumn('number', '2');
                    data.addColumn('number', '3');
                    data.addColumn('number', '4');
                    data.addColumn('number', '5');
                    data.addColumn('number', '6');
                    data.addColumn('number', '7');
                data.addRows([
                           ['24',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['25',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['26',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['27',0,0,0,0,1776,7000,0],
                           ['28',40,0,0,0,4737,4123,0],
                           ['29',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['30',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['31',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   ]);
        
        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: '2015-08',
                minValue: 0
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'Сумма (руб.)',
              viewWindow: { min : 0}
            },
            height: 350,
            curveType: 'function',
            colors: ['#00FFFF','#0000FF','#FF00FF','#808080','#008000','#00FF00','#800000','#000080','#808000','#FF0000','#C0C0C0','#008080']
        };
```

[Пример возможного графика](https://jsfiddle.net/DarkVss/0yds4yz1/1/)

Как можно сделать чтобы по щелчку по имени графика в легенде,он не только выделялся,но и остальные скрывались.

Может кто-то подобное делал и есть решения в гугле, без написания своих костылей))

Просто некоторые значения(по сравнению с другими) могут быть чертовским малыми- ['28',40,0,0,0,4737,4123,0], и их будет проблемно увидеть.

Конечно выводимые данные дублируются на странице в виде таблицы-но манагерам легче видеть графическое представление....